# Get dynamic Coordinates of created subview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, cgrectmake

I created a method that creates a subview based on the input size so there is not a defined and default corner CGRect values.I want to create a dismiss button that will be located at the top left corner of each subview. Currently I'm using this method to add it, but the problem with this is that the values for CGRectMake can not be static.

```
CGRect tapToDismissFrame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f);

UIButton *tapToDismiss = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:tapToDismissFrame];
tapToDismiss.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tapToDismiss.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Helvetica-Bold"] size:20];
[tapToDismiss setTitle:@"⊗" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tapToDismiss setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:173.0/255.0 green:36.0/255.0  blue:36.0/255.0  alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tapToDismiss addTarget:self action:@selector(tapToDismissClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.maskView addSubview:tapToDismiss];
```

How can i get the dynamic values in order to create it in the top left or right corner.

Comment: Why don't you use layout constraints to position your button?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html) functions to calculate correct frame for your dismiss button. Suppose you created that button. After that point here is a sample code:

```
[button sizeToFit];
CGRect maskViewBounds = self.maskView.bounds;
CGFloat top = CGRectGetMinY(maskViewBounds);
CGRect left = CGRectGetMaxX(maskViewBounds);
CGFloat buttonHeight = button.size.height;
CGFloat buttonWidth = button.size.width;
CGFloat topMargin = 5.0f;
CGFloat leftMargin = 5.0f;
CGPoint buttonCenter = CGPointMake(top + buttonHeight / 2.0 + topMargin, left - buttonWidth / 2.0 - leftMargin);
button.center = buttonCenter;
```

Note: I didn't write this code in Xcode. So there may be type errors.

Comment: sorry man it doesnt work, i corrected the errors but no use     
    
    [tapToDismiss sizeToFit];
    CGRect maskViewBounds = self.maskView.bounds;
    CGFloat top = CGRectGetMinY(maskViewBounds);
    CGFloat left = CGRectGetMaxX(maskViewBounds);
    CGFloat buttonHeight = tapToDismiss.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = tapToDismiss.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat topMargin = 5.0f;
    CGFloat leftMargin = 5.0f;
    CGPoint buttonCenter = CGPointMake(top + buttonHeight / 2.0 + topMargin, left - buttonWidth / 2.0 - leftMargin);
    tapToDismiss.center = buttonCenter;

Comment: No I mean if you are doing this stuff in `viewDidLoad` it won't work. Because at the time of `viewDidLoad` called the view frames are not set. So all the calculation will be based on false values. You should move the calculation codes into the `viewDidLayoutSubViews` method.

Comment: nope it doesnt work and beside that , i need a more general solution since i'm creating by subview in a header file that will be available for all view controllers i cant just go and create viewdidlayout for each one of them

Comment: Then if you know Auto Layout use it.